# Subdomains with Magento

Tags: magento, nginx

THis is probably a dumb question, but I am currently moving to a new install of Magento. I'm on a Ubuntu server with nginx. The current installation is at /var/www, but I moved it to /var/wwwOLD so that the new site could be at /var/www. Is there a way to access the old site without renaming the new directory one to something else and the old one back to /var/www?

Sorry if this doesn't make much sense or is a common sense question that I should already know.

Answer (score 0):

You setup a duplicated version of Magento in a separate folder by doing the following.

1. Configure a subdomain that points to the old folder.  Example: `oldsite.yoursite.com`
2. Duplicate the Magento database to a new database
3. Edit the `core_config_data` table in the duplicated Magento database and edit the records with the **path** values `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` to the `oldsite.yoursite.com` domain value.
4. Edit the **app/etc/local.xml** file to point to your duplicated database (the one with your updated urls in the `core_config_data` table)
5. Delete everything in the `var/cache` folder.